# Pyhive+Pandas: TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes when running query for larger number of rows(>1000)

Tags: python, sql, hive, thrift, pyhive

My code in its simplest form looks as below. I'm trying to connect to hive from a jupyter notebook. I code works fine when I query for smaller number of rows say 'select * from table limit 200' but throws this error when  I do something like 'select * from table', the table is around 180MB and can be easily loaded in memory. I'm not sure why this is happening. Any help is much appreciated! I looked at the other similar questions, but they were not helpful

> ```
> package versions -
>     python - 3.7
>     pandas - 0.24.2
>     pyhive 0.6.1
> ```

```
import pandas
import os
from pyhive import hive
def hiveconnection(query):
    conn = hive.Connection(host=HOST, port=10000, username=USER, 
                       password=PASSWORD, auth='LDAP')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    result = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()

    return result
query = """select * from table"""
df_new = hiveconnection(query)
```

The query runs fine and I get results for smaller resultset say - `select * from table limit 200`
But I get the following error when I query for larger number of rows.

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TTransportException                       Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 query = """select * from sample_table"""
> ----> 2 df_new = hiveconnection(query)
>
> in hiveconnection(query)
> 7     cur = conn.cursor()
> 8     cur.execute(query)
> ----> 9     result = cur.fetchall()
> 10     conn.close()
> 11
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyhive/common.py in
> fetchall(self)
> 134         :py:meth:`execute` did not produce any result set or no call was issued yet.
> 135         """
> --> 136         return list(iter(self.fetchone, None))
> 137
> 138     @property
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyhive/common.py in
> fetchone(self)
> 103
> 104         # Sleep until we're done or we have some data to return
> --> 105         self._fetch_while(lambda: not self._data and self._state != self._STATE_FINISHED)
> 106
> 107         if not self._data:
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyhive/common.py in
> _fetch_while(self, fn)
> 43     def _fetch_while(self, fn):
> 44         while fn():
> ---> 45             self._fetch_more()
> 46             if fn():
> 47                 time.sleep(self._poll_interval)
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py in
> _fetch_more(self)
> 384             maxRows=self.arraysize,
> 385         )
> --> 386         response = self._connection.client.FetchResults(req)
> 387         _check_status(response)
> 388         schema = self.description
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/TCLIService/TCLIService.py
> in FetchResults(self, req)
> 712         """
> 713         self.send_FetchResults(req)
> --> 714         return self.recv_FetchResults()
> 715
> 716     def send_FetchResults(self, req):
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/TCLIService/TCLIService.py
> in recv_FetchResults(self)
> 731             raise x
> 732         result = FetchResults_result()
> --> 733         result.read(iprot)
> 734         iprot.readMessageEnd()
> 735         if result.success is not None:
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/TCLIService/TCLIService.py
> in read(self, iprot)    3468                 if ftype == TType.STRUCT:
> 3469                     self.success = TFetchResultsResp()
> -> 3470                     self.success.read(iprot)    3471                 else:    3472                     iprot.skip(ftype)
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/TCLIService/ttypes.py
> in read(self, iprot)    6581                 if ftype == TType.STRUCT:
> 6582                     self.results = TRowSet()
> -> 6583                     self.results.read(iprot)    6584                 else:    6585                     iprot.skip(ftype)
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/TCLIService/ttypes.py
> in read(self, iprot)    2865                     for _i114 in
> range(_size110):    2866                         _elem115 = TColumn()
> -> 2867                         _elem115.read(iprot)    2868                         self.columns.append(_elem115)    2869
> iprot.readListEnd()
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/TCLIService/ttypes.py
> in read(self, iprot)    2727                 if ftype == TType.STRUCT:
> 2728                     self.i64Val = TI64Column()
> -> 2729                     self.i64Val.read(iprot)    2730                 else:    2731                     iprot.skip(ftype)
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/TCLIService/ttypes.py
> in read(self, iprot)    2351                     (_etype79, _size76) =
> iprot.readListBegin()    2352                     for _i80 in
> range(_size76):
> -> 2353                         _elem81 = iprot.readI64()    2354                         self.values.append(_elem81)    2355
> iprot.readListEnd()
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py
> in readI64(self)
> 220
> 221     def readI64(self):
> --> 222         buff = self.trans.readAll(8)
> 223         val, = unpack('!q', buff)
> 224         return val
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py
> in readAll(self, sz)
> 60         have = 0
> 61         while (have < sz):
> ---> 62             chunk = self.read(sz - have)
> 63             chunkLen = len(chunk)
> 64             have += chunkLen
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/**init**.py
> in read(self, sz)
> 171       return ret
> 172
> --> 173     self._read_frame()
> 174     return ret + self.__rbuf.read(sz - len(ret))
> 175
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/**init**.py
> in _read_frame(self)
> 188     else:
> 189       # If the frames are not encoded, just pass it through
> --> 190       decoded = self._trans.read(length)
> 191     self.__rbuf = BufferIO(decoded)
> 192
>
> /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py
> in read(self, sz)
> 141         if len(buff) == 0:
> 142             raise TTransportException(type=TTransportException.END_OF_FILE,
> --> 143                                       message='TSocket read 0 bytes')
> 144         return buff
> 145
>
> TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes